# Selecting All Data In Column Containing Blanks

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to select a range which takes in all data in a column (not including the header) that contains an unknown number of blank cells. I tried:

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Offset(1).Select
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to select the entire column (minus the header row) or do you only want the blank cells in that column?

Comment: Dan I'm looking for the entire column minus the header row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim cl As String
    cl = "E"
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, cl).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(cl & "2:" & cl & N).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Range("E2:E" & Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Select
```

You could, of course, add a variable in place of the `E` if you wish, but this will highlight from Row 2 down to as far as you have data entered.